# Can the bluetooth API in chrome be used as a server?

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth, google-chrome-app, chromium

Is it possible to use the bluetooth javascript extension API to implement a bluetooth server (in other words, listen on a socket) which can allow a device (bluetooth client) to connect?

According to current documentation and the very few examples, I found it unclear if this is a possibility.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_bluetooth#listening

```
var uuid = '1105';
chrome.bluetoothSocket.create(function(createInfo) {
    chrome.bluetoothSocket.onAccept.addListener(function(acceptInfo) {
        if (info.socketId != createInfo.socketId) return;

        // Say hello...
        chrome.bluetoothSocket.send(acceptInfo.clientSocketId,
            data, onSendCallback);

        // Accepted sockets are initially paused,
        // set the onReceive listener first.
        chrome.bluetoothSocket.onReceive.addListener(onReceive);
        chrome.bluetoothSocket.setPaused(acceptInfo.clientSocketId, false);
    });

    chrome.bluetoothSocket.listenUsingRfcomm(
        createInfo.socketId, uuid, function() {
            // check chrome.runtime.lastError
        });
});
```